# System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'.'

Tags: c#

I run a page-style application

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApp1.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="Page1">
<Page.Resources>
  ......
</Page>
```

The error message is as follows:

```
System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'.'
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Edit startupUri in App.xaml file.** 
In your case you mentioned you're running a page style application, so i assume "WpfApp1.Page1" is the startup page, so **StartupUri="WpfApp1/Page1.xaml"**

Answer (score 0):

You probably moved the page into a folder so maybe you created a folder called **Views** for example and you moved that page into it. So you go to the App.xaml and located the **StartupUri** and in the startup you put **"/Views/Page1.xaml"** so that should all be in one line like:

**StartupUri="/Views/Page1.xaml"**